# NSDate Converting issue with constant time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am having issues with date conversion 
I need output as 2016-5-03 24:00:00
But Current output is 2016-5-03 00:00:00

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let sevenDaysAgo = calendar!.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -7, toDate: todaysDate, options: [])           

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-M-dd 00:00:00"
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sevenDaysAgo!)
print("startdates is \(dateString)")
start = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

let enddateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
enddateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd 24:00:00"
let enddateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sevenDaysAgo!)
print("enddates is \(enddateString)")
```

Comment: `24:00` is not a valid time or date format. Why do you want that time?

Answer (score 2):

Typo:

```
let enddateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sevenDaysAgo!)
                    ^ should have been enddateFormatter
```